# Does it make sense to implement md-data-table for angular material design?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, material-design, angular-material

I just created the md-data-table repository based on google material.
It will be an extension for angular-material design:

https://github.com/iamisti/md-data-table

demo: http://iamisti.github.io/md-data-table/

Does it make sense to implement?

I mean, I didnt see any md-data-table in the milestone of angular material (which I dont see why). So that I just want to make sure, I don't waste my time.

Comment: Hi there! I myself felt the missing of table in angular-material and I was looking for it. I am obsessed with Google Material Design, so i would really use your `md-data-table`. Cheers

Comment: @SalalAslam thanks! I'm continously working on it. Mark the repository and you will get notified, once I have a release. ;)

Comment: Thank you! also it would be great if you can implement [datepicker](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/pickers.html) too :)

Comment: datepicker can wait, but we'll see. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update: This answer is from 2015. What was said below about the feature did not arrive.**

As **ThomasBurleson** wrote about a month ago in [this github comment on an issue](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3343) similar to your question or poll here.

> This is a very important component for Angular Material and any UI 
>   Component library.
>
> With the current schedule and goals for v1.0, however, the mdDataTable
>   will be implemented after the v1.0 release of Angular Material.

At the time of writing ng-material is on version 0.10/0.10.1-rc1, and it has been stated they are working for a v1 release this summer.

**ThomasBurleson** again: ([source](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2978#issuecomment-114899993))

> Angular Material 1.0 has a planned release for summer of 2015.

I'm sure I've seen some implementations of datatables so far by the ng/ng-material community, so I guess we'll have to make do with user-contributed solutions for now. (user-created datatable [here](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3343) or [here](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/796))

Comment: I guess you meant summer of 2016? ;P

Comment: It still hasn't been included in the current version at https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/. Is there a way to see the current timeline for new releases?

Comment: still waiting for this feature but haven't seen it... @supersan have you found anything?

Comment: well, I suppose it will never get into angular-material since ThomasBurleson has been quite busy closing most of the angular-material 1 issues because they're focusing on angular-material 2.. so much for "ang-material 1" will be supported. right

Comment: Updated my answer to not bring too much false hope